# Cannot serialize a string object with Microsoft.Bond

Tags: bond

I am using Microsoft.Bond to serialize a class object which works perfectly fine. However, when I try to serialize a simple System.String object, the CompactBinaryWriter writes almost nothing to the output buffer. I am using this code:

```cs
string v = "test data";
var outputBuffer = new OutputBuffer();
var writer = new CompactBinaryWriter<OutputBuffer>(outputBuffer);
Serialize.To(writer, v);
var output = outputBuffer.Data;
```

`output` in this case is a one element array : {0}, irrespective of the value of v. Can someone point out why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Bond requires a top-level Bond struct to perform serialization/deserialization.

If only one value needs to be passed/returned, the type `bond.Box<T>` can be used to quickly wrap a value in a Bond struct. (There's nothing special about `bond.Box<T>`, except that it ships with Bond.)

Try this:

```cs
Serialize.To(writer, Bond.Box.Create(v));
```

You'll need to deserialize into a `bond.Box<string>`.

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/bond/issues/428) about having better behavior in cases like this.